# How do I set the collection for the years in a simple-form field with a date format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, collections, simple-form

I'm using simple-form, but I'm having a hard time to show the date_of_birth correctly. This is probably because of a combination of limited documentation on simple-form and more so the fact that I'm a rooky.

Anyways, I'm trying to create a collection of the years people can choose from for their birthdate.

date_of_birth is an attribute of the user in the DATE form, which requires input of a year, month and day. Now I tried to change the collection for the years as below, but this removes the input fields for day and month:

```
= simple_form_for(@user, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|
  ...
  = f.input :date_of_birth, :collection => 1910..2010
```

I'm using Simple-form on Ruby on Rails with HAML. So question is: What is the correct way to just define the collection for the years, keeping the defaults for the input of day and month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following code should do the trick:

```
f.input :date_of_birth, :as => :date,
        :start_year => 1910, :end_year => 2010,
        :order => [:day, :month, :year]
```

(The previous code is untested and could cause the end of the world as Mayan predicted)

You can find the documentation for SimpeForm [here](http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br/#information/rdocs) (try to look for date_of_birth ;))

Comment: Great, thanks. Don't know how I missed that, sorry. Just one more thing. On the documentation page is mentioned that 'select_year' should work too, but when I add ':select_year => 1990' it does not seem to change anything. Could you show how that should be implemented? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fritzz where is this mentioned? I can't find in the page I linked. Glad to know it worked BTW ;)

Comment: On [your link](http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br/#information/rdocs) it says SimpleForm accepts same options as their corresponding input type helper in Rails. When I look in the [type helper documention](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_year), these functions are shown. Select_year does not seem to work however.

I think I should be using the ':default =>' function... Just figuring out how I should format the date so it works correctly.

Comment: I figured it out. Using ':default => "1980-01-01".to_date' did the trick. It makes sense this is the most logic way to do this, right?

Comment: As far as I know select_year is not an option is a form helper[1] used to generate a select to generate just the year select.

To do what you want to do you should use the :default option.

[1]: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#individual-components